# Why are my widgets not showing up on the 3rd screen

Tags: python, tkinter

When you select 2 duelist on the second screen the program shows a 3rd screen that should display 2 labels and 2 entry widgets for the user to enter the names of the players. But I can't seem to figure out why the widgets are not showing up. The section of code that involves this issue is the the block for the class TwoPlayer. Thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk


largeFont = ("Veranda", 18)
field1 = 'Duelist 1', 'Duelist 2' 
names = []

class Yugioh_backEnd(tk.Tk):
    #set default initializion 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "YuGiOh Duel Calculator")

        #containers
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        #set pack method for container
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        #set grid method for container
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #selects which frame to show
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, NumPlayers, TwoPlayer):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F]=frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        #show Frame
        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #greet the user
        greeting = tk.Label(self, text = "Welcome to\n YuGiOh Duel Calculator!", font = largeFont)
        greeting.pack(pady=(10,40),padx=30)

        #Enter the next window
        lets_duel = tk.Button(self, text="Lets Duel!!!",                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NumPlayers))
        lets_duel.pack(pady=(0,30),padx=30)

class NumPlayers(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #prompt for players quantity
        prompt1 = tk.Label(self, text = "How many duelist?", font = largeFont)

        prompt1.pack(pady=(10,40),padx=30)

        #Number of players
        twoPlayers = tk.Button(self, text = "2 Duelists", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TwoPlayer))

        return1 = tk.Button(self, text="Return Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        #Add buttons to frame
        return1.pack(pady=(0,30),padx=30)
        twoPlayers.pack(pady=(0,10),padx=30)


#Two player mode
class TwoPlayer(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        def makeform(field1):

           for field in field1:
              row = tk.Frame()
              lab = tk.Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
              ent = tk.Entry(row)
              row.pack(side="top", padx=5, pady=5)
              lab.pack(side="left")
              ent.pack(side="right")
              names.append((field, ent))
           return names

        if __name__ == ("__init__"):
               ents = makeform(field1) 
               b1 = tk.Button(text='Show',
                      command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
               b1.pack(padx=5, pady=5)



app = Yugioh_backEnd()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your indention is bad for one. Make sure that all indention levels are consistent. Preferable 4 spaces each per PEP8 standards. 2nd I am not sure why you have `if __name__ == ("__init__"):` in your class. Also you are trying to apply pack and grid at the same time to the container. You can only use one or the other per container.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. As far as indention according to Idle it is correct since that is what I'm using as the interpreter for the program as of right now. you replace the ("__init__") with ("__main__"). Thank the widgets are able to display but displays on all windows. I'm fully aware you can't use grid and pack at the same time. The frame.grid gets ignored since I have all the widgets using the pack method. It is set there if I decide it is necessary to move everything over to a grid design instead of packed. If you have other ideas I am open to hearing them.